# Elasticsearch _query vs _search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a question which is not quite clear for me when reading the documentation.
What exactly is the difference between the `_search` and the `_query` Endpoint?

Thanks a lot!
Matthias

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `_search` API endpoint allows you to execute a search query and get back search hits that match the query. The query can either be provided using a simple query string as a parameter, or using a request body.

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet,user/_search?q=user:kimchy'


curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/_search' -d '{
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
    }
}
'
```

The `_query` endpoint, is for delete by query only (I think it only has handlers for DELETE, not POST, or GET).

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/_query?q=user:kimchy'
```

You can learn more here:
[Elasticsearch Doco](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-search.html)